# low:events excluding an entry

Tags: low-variables, parse-order, low, events, low-events

I'm using low:events:entries. I have a page that shows the next upcoming featured event as a picture, then underneath it a list of events, both featured and non-featured. My next upcoming featured event is showing up both in the picture and in the list, and I'd like it to not show up in the list since that looks like a duplicate.

It's under "Upcoming Events" at [www.fcs.uga.edu](http://www.fcs.uga.edu).

I've tried using the entry_id="not {lv_exclude_id}" parameter when making the list, defining lv_exclude_id, an early-parsed Low Variable, as:

```
{exp:low_events:entries channel="events" show_passed="no" search:events_front_page_feature="Yes" limit="1"}
{entry_id}
{/exp:low_events:entries}
```

(The same tag that brings up my one featured event.)

But that's not working. Maybe seeding one low:events:entries with another isn't the way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an early parsed var (or a Snippet for that matter) like that doesn't work. To illustrate, using the var you geva as an example, and using it like this:

```
{exp:low_events:entries entry_id="not {lv_exclude_id}"}
    ...
{/exp:low_events:entries}
```

...will result in this code when we come to the stage where tags are parsed:

```
{exp:low_events:entries entry_id="not {exp:low_events:entries channel="events" show_passed="no" search:events_front_page_feature="Yes" limit="1"}
        {entry_id}
    {/exp:low_events:entries}"}
    ...
{/exp:low_events:entries}
```

You can see why this will not work.

So, to work around it, you'd need to use either an embed, or something like Stash.

Comment: I actually tried Stash and an embed, as well, and neither worked. Both are outputting the correct value right before I open the low_events:entries tag, but inside the tag defining entry_id="not {embed or stash reference}" something must be going wrong. Parse order I assume?

Comment: You should be looking at something like `entry_id="not {embed:entry_id}"` instead of putting the actual embed tag in there. Check out the docs on embeds/layouts on the EE site.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I was passing the embed (which returned a value) as a parameter in low:events:entries, when I should have included the entire low:events:entries block in an embed like {embed="embeds/include_latest_events" exclude_id="{exp:stash:get name="exclude_id"}"}.